# How to get description of database mirroring state

Tags: t-sql, sql-server-2008-r2, database-mirroring

I've set up alerts on my SQL server to alert me when the mirroring state of any of my mirrored databases changes, as per [this article](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc966392.aspx).

It's all working fine but I was wondering if there was any way, via T-SQL, to get the description of a database mirroring state from the state ID provided by **$(WMI(State))** ?

The article I linked to provides a list of all the possible states and what they mean, so I could create my own table or use a CASE statement, but it would be nice if I could use  built-in function or select from an existing table.  Maybe my Google-Power is low today, but I've not been able to find anything.

Comment: [`sys.database_mirroring`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178655.aspx)? (Although you'd go from a database ID rather than a state ID)

Comment: The mirroring_state_desc column of that view refers to something different I think.  Either way, it only shows the current state, which is no good for my purposes as I want to describe a state that only exists for a moment (e.g. State 7 is "Manual Failover").  I have an alert that captures that **State 7** has occurred, and a t-SQL script that emails me that **State 7** has occurred, but want to be able to convert "7" to "Manual Failover".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To do this I ended up adding a CASE statement to my script - I could have created a table but this is more portable as I wanted to copy the script to several different servers.

```
declare @MirrorStateDesc varchar(50)
select @MirrorStateDesc = '$(ESCAPE_NONE(WMI(State)))'
select @MirrorStateDesc = CASE @MirrorStateDesc WHEN '7' THEN 'Manual Failover' WHEN '8' THEN 'Automatic Failover' WHEN '10' THEN 'No Quorum' WHEN '12' THEN 'Principle Running Exposed' ELSE @MirrorStateDesc  END
```

I'm only using this script on states 7, 8, 10 and 12 so they are the only ones I added to my case statement.  The other values and descriptions are on the page I linked to in the question, if anybody wants to expand the script for their own uses.

I'm still surprised that there isn't a built in function to do this though!

Comment: Did you find a reference source for your number to name mapping?

Comment: Never mind, http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc966392.aspx#XSLTsection128121120120 has a list